# GNOME under Wayland does not start after updating to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, wayland, 23.10

Hello Ubuntu community,

I recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and since then (1 Week) I've had problems starting GNOME under Wayland. Here are the details of my system and the steps already taken:

**System information:**

- Device: MS Surface Pro 5 (Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640)
- Ubuntu version: 10/23
- Kernel: Linux 6.5.6-surface

**Description of the problem:**

After updating to Ubuntu 23.10, the GNOME window manager no longer starts under Wayland. X.org, however, works fine. However, in my opinion the quality of the display is lower (screen tearing, flickering mouse, low fps)

**Screen resolution and scaling:**

I use an external monitor with 1920x1080px and 100% scaling. The built-in screen has a resolution of 2736x1824px and a scaling of 200%. Fractional scaling is enabled.

**Steps already taken:**

- All available updates have been installed.
- Fractional scaling has been disabled.
- I tried to force Wayland by adding "WaylandEnable=True" in the "gdm3 custom.conf".
- Automatic login (without entering a password) has been deactivated.
- I tried reinstalling "libglib2.0-0".
- Various Linux kernels tested: Linux 6.5.6-surface, Linux 6.3.2-surface, Linux 6.5.0-9-generic (Wayland does not work under all of them)

**Log (journalctl) from login screen (gdm Debug)**

[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hm8QjmRknCMAhKwOhjHc2mgvbYsBWzKO/view?usp=sharing)

**Coredump**

```
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 kernel: gnome-shell[10804]: segfault at 78 ip 00007f9bfd197c2b sp 00007f9bccff7de0 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7800.0[7f9bfd103000+9a000] likely on CPU 3 (core 1, socket 0)
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 kernel: Code: 0f 1e fa 53 89 fb e8 74 c6 f6 ff 83 f8 ff 74 02 5b c3 89 df e8 76 dd f6 ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 41 54 55 48 89 fd 53 <48> 8b 1f 48 89 df 48 85 db 74 12 e8 45 cc f6 ff 85 c0 75 41 5b 5d
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 systemd[1]: Started systemd-coredump@2-10847-0.service - Process Core Dump (PID 10847/UID 0).
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 systemd-coredump[10848]: Process 10744 (gnome-shell) of user 1000 dumped core.
                                                               
                                                               Module libudev.so.1 from deb systemd-253.5-1ubuntu6.amd64
                                                               Module libsystemd.so.0 from deb systemd-253.5-1ubuntu6.amd64
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10804:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfd197c2b g_rw_lock_writer_lock (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb2c2b)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfcd657c1 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x1657c1)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfcd65df6 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x165df6)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfcd8c803 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x18c803)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfcd8e424 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x18e424)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10744:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc925c7d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x125c7d)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd1967e4 g_cond_wait (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb17e4)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfcd862db n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x1862db)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfd2a7c33 g_initable_new_valist (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bc33)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd2a7d1d g_initable_new (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bd1d)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfcd89764 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x189764)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfd6ff2c3 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x252c3)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfd701273 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x27273)
                                                               #8  0x00007f9bfd7015cd g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x275cd)
                                                               #9  0x00007f9bfcd606cf n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x1606cf)
                                                               #10 0x00007f9bfcc7604c n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0x7604c)
                                                               #11 0x00007f9bfd2a7c33 g_initable_new_valist (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bc33)
                                                               #12 0x00007f9bfd2a7d1d g_initable_new (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bd1d)
                                                               #13 0x00007f9bfccc8d29 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0xc8d29)
                                                               #14 0x00007f9bfcccf821 n/a (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0xcf821)
                                                               #15 0x00007f9bfcccfd43 meta_context_setup (libmutter-13.so.0 + 0xcfd43)
                                                               #16 0x000055bf99d4ad11 n/a (gnome-shell + 0x3d11)
                                                               #17 0x00007f9bfc8280d0 __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x280d0)
                                                               #18 0x00007f9bfc828189 __libc_start_main_impl (libc.so.6 + 0x28189)
                                                               #19 0x000055bf99d4b355 n/a (gnome-shell + 0x4355)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10761:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc925c7d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x125c7d)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd197140 g_cond_wait_until (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb2140)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfd10bc83 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x26c83)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfd172a8a n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8da8a)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10759:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc925c7d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x125c7d)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd1967e4 g_cond_wait (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb17e4)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfd10bcab n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x26cab)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfd171e0a n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8ce0a)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10764:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfa93b3f9 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl4waitERNS0_9MutexImplE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93b3f9)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfa93d555 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl8wait_forERNS0_9MutexImplERKNS_16BaseTimeDurationINS_27TimeDurationValueCalculatorEEE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93d555)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfa2191ee n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x2191ee)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfa217027 n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x217027)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10779:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10760:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc91a18f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x11a18f)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd19b3cf n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb63cf)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfd13dd20 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x58d20)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfd13dd71 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x58d71)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10802:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10763:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc91a18f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x11a18f)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd19b3cf n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb63cf)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfd13dd20 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x58d20)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bf861d20d n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0x720d)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10803:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10765:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfa93b3f9 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl4waitERNS0_9MutexImplE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93b3f9)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfa93d555 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl8wait_forERNS0_9MutexImplERKNS_16BaseTimeDurationINS_27TimeDurationValueCalculatorEEE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93d555)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfa2191ee n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x2191ee)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfa217027 n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x217027)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10766:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfa93b3f9 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl4waitERNS0_9MutexImplE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93b3f9)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfa93d555 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl8wait_forERNS0_9MutexImplERKNS_16BaseTimeDurationINS_27TimeDurationValueCalculatorEEE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93d555)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfa2191ee n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x2191ee)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfa217027 n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x217027)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10767:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfa93b3f9 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl4waitERNS0_9MutexImplE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93b3f9)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfa93d555 _ZN7mozilla6detail21ConditionVariableImpl8wait_forERNS0_9MutexImplERKNS_16BaseTimeDurationINS_27TimeDurationValueCalculatorEEE (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x93d555)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfa2191ee n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x2191ee)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfa217027 n/a (libmozjs-115.so.0 + 0x217027)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #7  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10762:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc91a18f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x11a18f)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfd19b3cf n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xb63cf)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9bfd14046f g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5b46f)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9bfd33e59a n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x11259a)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9bfd170331 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8b331)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10778:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10777:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10780:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10799:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               
                                                               Stack trace of thread 10798:
                                                               #0  0x00007f9bfc894076 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x94076)
                                                               #1  0x00007f9bfc8969fe __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x969fe)
                                                               #2  0x00007f9be4f1ed2d n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ed2d)
                                                               #3  0x00007f9be4ecf1bb n/a (iris_dri.so + 0xcf1bb)
                                                               #4  0x00007f9be4f1ec5b n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x11ec5b)
                                                               #5  0x00007f9bfc897ada start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x97ada)
                                                               #6  0x00007f9bfc92847c __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x12847c)
                                                               ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@2-10847-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 22 18:10:28 ckoever-Surface-Pro-5 systemd[6134]: org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [garudalinux](https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/gnome-45-wayland-session/31493) forum thread:

> i fixed it . i deleted every extension i had installed , then deleted the dconf folder in ./config , it did the trick for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Good to know it helped you, but please don't use the answers section for "me too" other comments - thanks!